# Concatenate field names in select

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, forms, activerecord

I have a form that allows you to select a facility by name then writes the id of the facility to a vale in the database.

```
<%= f.collection_select(:transfer_to_id, Facility.all, :id, :facility_name, {:include_blank => true}, {:class => 'select'})%>
```

I'd like to be able to select the facility name but to the right of the facility name display the facility_address in the form.  I'm not sure how to do this, possibly an array of some sort or using a helper method.

If anyone can provide some help it would be appreciated.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to concatenate the name and address of the facility in the select box? e.g. `Facility X - 123 Abc Street`?

Comment: Exactly.  I came up with this, but not sure if it's right. ' def facility_select
    Facility.order("facility_name").map{|facility| ["#{facility.facility_name} #{facility.facility_address}", facility.id]}
  end'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what ended up working properly for me by creating a Class method.

```
  def facility_name_with_facility_address
    "#{facility_name} | #{facility_address}"
  end
```

Answer (score 2):

This is untested so bear with me, but you need to add a method to your `Facility` model:

```
def facility_name_with_facility_address
  facility_name << " " << facility_address
end
```

And then in your form you want to change the following:

```
<%= f.collection_select(:transfer_to_id, Facility.all, :id, :facility_name, {:include_blank => true}, {:class => 'select'})%>
```

To this:

```
<%= f.collection_select(:transfer_to_id, Facility.all, :id, :facility_name_with_facility_address, {:include_blank => true}, {:class => 'select'})%>
```